# Regex expression to match last numerical component, but exclude file extension

Tags: python, regex

I'm stumped trying to figure out a regex expression. Given a file path, I need to match the last numerical component of the path ("frame" number in an image sequence), but also ignore any numerical component in the file extension.

For example, given path:

`/path/to/file/abc123/GCAM5423.xmp`

The following expression will correctly match `5423`.

`((?P<index>(?P<padding>0*)\d+)(?!.*(0*)\d+))`

However, this expression fails if for example the file extension contains a number as follows:

`/path/to/file/abc123/GCAM5423.cr2`

In this case the expression will match the `2` in the file extension, when I still need it to match `5423`. How can I modify the above expression to ignore file extensions that have a numerical component?

Using python flavor of regex. Thanks in advance!

Edit: Thanks all for your help! To clarify, I specifically need to modify the above expression to only capture the last group. I am passing this pattern to an external library so it needs to include the named groups and to only match the last number prior to the extension.

Comment: Is it guaranteed that the files will have an extension?  If so, you could just look for a period following the number.

Comment: Yes, its safe to count on the extension. Any suggestions for how to modify the above pattern to look for the period?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this one:
`\/[a-zA-Z]*(\d*)\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{3,4}$`

Answer (score 1):

Try this pattern:
`\/[^/\d\s]+(\d+)\.[^/]+$`

See Regex [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gPfcTx/1)

Code:

```
import re

pattern = r"\/[^/\d\s]+(\d+)\.[^/]+$"

texts = ['/path/to/file/abc123/GCAM5423.xmp', '/path/to/file/abc123/GCAM5423.cr2']

print([match.group(1) for x in texts if (match := re.search(pattern, x))])
```

Output:

`['5423', '5423']`

Answer (score 0):

Step1: Find substring before last dot.

```
(.*)\.
```

Input: `/path/to/file/abc123/GCAM5423.cr2`

Output: `/path/to/file/abc123/GCAM5423`

Step2: Find the last numbers using your regex.

Input: `/path/to/file/abc123/GCAM5423`

Output: `5423`

I don't know how to join these two regexs, but it also usefult for you. My hopes^_^